# Printing from Vim colors too bright

Tags: vim, printing

When I print from `vim` using `:ha`, everything is great, except yellow is freakishly bright. How to tell `vim` to darken the yellow when printing with `:ha`?

Comment: My best bet would be to change the color scheme before printing with po=syntax:y

Comment: @sehe you mean :set printoptions=syntax:y ? I've tried that, still ridiculesly bright...

Comment: Yes, either change the color scheme to a more printer-friendly-one, or use black&white color scheme for printing (i.e. disregard syntax highlighting).

Comment: wich colorscheme do you suggest I use for printing ruby code? and how to install/set up that colorscheme?

Comment: @oFca no, I meant change `:colorscheme` _when_ printing with `syntax:y` (conversely: print with `syntax:n`)

Comment: @sehe sorry, but I'm a bit slow, I don't understand... Can you please literally write what I should write in vim before typing :ha ? Also, I would like to solve this in my ~/.vimrc file, so if you know, write the line for that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer from some great guy in IRC at freenode.net. (**rking** if someone knows him :)

Anyway, **this solution works perfectly for me.** By pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>, it opens file I was editing in vim in browser (in the case below in chrome), and all I have to do is right click > print.

Anyway here's the code you should add to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
:map <f12> :TOhtml<cr>:%s/#ffff00/#aaaa00/g<cr>:w<cr>:!chromium-browser --print file://`pwd`/%<cr>:!rm %<cr>:q<cr>
```

Notice that you can specify the shade of the color you wish to change (in this case yellow) and modify it. It even gets rid of the duplicate file created by the :w command. Also, this code is modified for Ubuntu, with other OSs it might need some modification.

**There is only one bug** > `!chromium-browser --print` should print it automatically but it doesn't. I need to manually print it from the browser. Minor nuance, but if someone can solve this up, I would greatly appreciate :)

Comment: resourceful; not really a vim answer, but resourceful +1

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a way to just print readable code, you might just

```
:set printoptions-=syntax:y
:set printoptions+=syntax:n
```

before you do

```
:hardcopy
```

Otherwise, you might choose a colorscheme without yellow(ish) colors before printing

Comment: Or set "grayscale" (or whatever it's called) in his print options. Most printers have that option nowadays.

Comment: @ldigas With my laser printer, the yellow would still not be very readable

Comment: i found the solution i was looking for. i posted it as the answer here :)